# Rails link_to different resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I now have:

```
= link_to 'Back <', @discussable
```

And @discussable could be a course with a title, or a group with a name(I wish I used the same name). So I want to display "Back to *course_title*" or "Back to *group_name*" depending on the @discussable type. How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models, you can create a method that each model has to respond to, such as `def title`, and from there you would call that.

Example:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  #code

  def title
    self.name
  end

end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  #code

  def title
    self.full_name
  end

end
```

Then you would just do:

```
= link_to "Back to #{@discussable.title} <", @discussable
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! That's a very clear answer catered to a newbie like me. I guess is kinda similar solution like Steve's. But I don't have to define a label for each model with your solution.

Comment: May I ask why you're defining a title method in the `Course` model that is calling the title method that you're defining in the `Course` model?

Comment: Good catch, I was trying to provide an example... and in that instance it wasn't a good one :) I'll change it up.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, to each of the model classes, I would add a `label` instance method that returns whatever value is appropriate, and then say...

= link_to "Back to #{@discussable.label} <", @discussable

Comment: Thanks Steve! That's such a smart solution, wondering if there are even more elegant ways of doing that.

Comment: Well, how elegant it is depends on the context.  If this is the only view, then this is about as elegant as you'll want to get.  If you're using this pattern in multiple places, then you might want to create a helper method for it that works something like `link_to_labeled 'Back to %s', @discussable`.  Actually, that reminds me that the above would actually be slightly more readable as `= link_to "Back to %s <" % @discussable.label, @discussable`.

Comment: Thanks for the more readable version. I learned a lot from both you and Mike. But too bad I could only check one answer.

Comment: np -- I'm glad we could help.